# How to set up references and import external modules as top-level objects in Typescript in Node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript

So this is a Typescript file structure and naming question.  I'm just starting to learn about Typescript classes and modules and I have a few questions on how to structure model logic across multiple files.

Say I have a small rest api written in node.js with User and Photo models, and it's a simple api that lets users register and upload a photo.

Assuming this file structure:

```
-app
   -models
      -user.js
      -photo.js
   -controller.js
```

1. In my controller is it better to use a reference path declaration or external modules when referencing models?  Does this overlap with just using a standard node.js require statement?
2. If I use an import statement to load the models as an external module, can I change the below example to move the export to the top-level so that I can just new up a User() rather than models.User().

for example, the models, and `anotherModel` seems a bit redundant - and I don't want to combine all the models into one file.

controller.js

```
import models = require('./models/user');
import anotherModel = require('./models/photo');
var newUser = new models.User();
var newMoment = new anotherModel.Moment();
```

user.js

```
export class User {
  name:string
}
```

photo.js

```
export class Photo {
  url:string
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `model / index.ts` and re-export all the models from that file for easier consumption. This is conventional node.js paradigm.

Comment: Could I see a link to an example or some doc?